# How to optimize the air pressure produced by a black pipe in the sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, flow

So, I'm thinking of ways of overdoing the passive aeration of my compost bin. Basic setup is a (60L) bin with a pipe with holes through the middle; air is supposed to flow into the pipe and its holes to supply the compost with oxygen.

That would probably work perfectly fine by itself. But I'd like to optimize things and take advantage of the intense afternoon sun hitting the balcony where the bin is. Composting works better if a) there's more oxygen, b) it's hotter, and c) humidity is high.

So my idea is something along the lines of: Install a black metal pipe vertically, hanging down from my balcony in the sun. Hot air rises in the pipe, goes through a water reservoir (to raise humidity, and also collect liquid draining from the compost so it doesn't interfere with the air collecting pipe - wouldn't want to accidentally rain compost goo on my lower neighbours!), and then into the bottom of the holey pipe in the compost bin.

Now I'm thinking about how to get the most air pressure out of the rising air. If my pipe is too short, air won't sufficiently heat up to rise efficiently; if it's too long, that results in a loss in air pressure. Same with diameter - too thin and it slows the air down; too wide and air doesn't heat up as much. Or instead of a pipe, I could use a black metal surface (like an old side panel of a PC case or something) with a glass pane in front to retain heat radiation - but that costs me vertical length.

I don't have a feeling for which of these parameters are most important. Can you give me some rule-of-thumby advice? I guess accurately calculating is a waste since materials etc introduce more paramters I don't know...

Edit: A diagram:

[image: A diagram.]

Edit 2: It occurs to me that it would be smarter to have a water reservoir at the entry point of the black pipe - to cool down the air first from evaporation. Maybe throw in some plants for extra surface. More difficult to build though.

Comment: Can you provide a picture (diagram) of your setup

Comment: @Pradyuman - updated with a diagram. Of course, I don't even know if the air pressure would be enough to bubble it through water, so the water reservoir part is kinda optional.

Comment: If you want humidity just get the reservoir and cover it with polyethylene sheet or glass sunlight will evaporate the water and humidity in compost will increase, if you want more oxygen flow you need a big collector with short exit,